# Making Parallel Payments with calculated regional taxes (PayPal)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am in the situation where I need to spilt a payment between multiple recipients in parallel, however they may be in different countries and different taxes may apply per payment receiver.

For this I am using PayPal's Adaptive Payments service, with the provided PHP SDK.

My VAT configuration in the accounts I have been testing with is as follows:
[image: PayPal regional taxes setup page with taxes applied to UK, USA and Spain.]

However on checkout no taxes are applied, even after logging into another account in one of the affected countries:

[image: PayPal checkout page showing payments to three accounts, none with tax applied.]

I have a very simple demonstration page hosted here:
http://paytest.kingston-fear.com/
This uses Sandbox accounts, yet the issue also occurs with live accounts with VAT set up.

I've tried to simplify the code as much as possible for demonstration purposes: https://github.com/XyploatKyrt/paytest/blob/master/checkout.php#L9

Answer (score 0):

The tax and shipping rates you set in your account only apply to Payments Standard transactions. Not Adaptive Payment or Express Checkout payments.